# jquery code ,what is wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code work fine but when i try again and page is not reloaded, if form is not true the border does not change anything.What is the problem ?

```
var subscribeform = $('#subscribe-form');

$(".btn-main").hover(function(){

        if(subscribeform = true){
            $(".btn-main").css("border-color", "#00FF42");
        }
        else if (subscribeform = false){
            $(".btn-main").css("border-color", "red");
        }
        else{
             $(".btn-main").css("border-color", "blue");
        }
});


$(".btn-main").focus(function(){

        if(subscribeform = true){
            $(".btn-main").css("border-bottom-color", "red");
        }
        else if (subscribeform = false){
            $(".btn-main").css("border-color", "lightgreen");
        }
        else{
             $(".btn-main").css("border-bottom-color", "#00FF42");
        }
});
```

Comment: You're doing assignments, not comparisons. It should be `if (... ==...)`, not `if (...=...)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use double equals for comparison:

```
if(subscribeform == true){
  ...
}
```

instead of

```
if(subscribeform = true){
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you assigned value in if condittion

```
if(subscribeform = true){
```

change to

```
if(subscribeform == true){
```

or

```
if(subscribeform){
```